# how to generate a Signed apk with reat native

Tags: android, react-native, apk, expo

I have finished my first react native app , i want to generate my signed apk , but i can not find how , all ressources on the net that I've read talk about a folder called android within my project , but me since i have used the commande react-create-native-app to creat my app there is no android folder , in expo documentations they are saying to config app.json i see there is no app json , i dont know how to generate that apk , get confused

Comment: When I generated my `react-native` project with `react-create-native-app` I felt frustrated when I did not see the ios and android folder inside. I have always generated the `IPA` and `APKs` opening those projects in their respective `IDE`. It gives much more visibility and ease to make changes directly in the configuration of the `xcode`, for `splash, icons, plist, targets, etc`. For this reason I have always used `react-native init`. This question is very useful for me, to consider using this tool that I have always rejected. upvote and favorites

Answer (score 0):

To get APK and IPA files from Expo project you need to run `exp build:status`

More details here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/building-standalone-apps.html

Hope it helps

Comment: what about this attribute : slug , what they mean by , should i put there a link where app should be hosted ? upload app to expo first ?

Comment: i see its a link where my project will stay , and after i will download my apk from expo ,

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out [fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane), which will greatly help you automate building apk and ipa files.